# address out of range when calling sw procedure

Tags: mips

I'm only just starting to learn mips. I am trying to write a simple program that adds 3 numbers together. The program should prompt 3 times for a number and then output the sum. Here is what I have written

```
.data 
  instructions: .asciiz "Please enter a number : "
.text
  main: 
   li $t0, 0x00 # i = false
   li $t1, 0x00 #sum = 0

   while: # while(i < 3 )
     bgt $t0, 0x02, exit
     b prompt

   prompt:
     li $v0, 0x04 # set IO to output string
     la $a0, instructions #load the address of instructions into $a0 for IO
     syscall # print
     li $v0, 0x05
     syscall
     sw $v0, 0x0($t3) #address out of range 0x000000
     add $t1,$t1,$t2
     b while

   exit:
     li $v0,0x01
     move $a0, $t1
     syscall
```

The error occurs as the sw procedure. The debugger tells me that `$t3` has a value of 0 which I expect, but I need to read the value from `$v0` and store it in `$t3`. I'm sure it's something I just don't understand about mips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sw` is an *instruction*, not a procedure.

Anyway, the purpose of `sw` is to store the contents of a register in memory. It sounds to me like you just want to copy the contents of one register to another register, so the instruction you should use is `move`:

```
move $t3,$v0    # $t3 = $v0
```

The same thing could be achieved in a couple of other ways, e.g.:

```
or $t3,$v0,$zero
```

But if you're just starting out with MIPS assembly I suggest you just use `move`.